# Perl warning locale while I call psql

Tags: postgresql, locale

I try to run `postgresql` on my `Ubuntu` server

```
myname@myserver:/home$ sudo -i -u postgres
postgres@myserver:~$ psql

perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = "en_US:",
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LC_CTYPE = "UTF-8",
    LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to a fallback locale ("en_US.UTF-8").

psql (9.5.14)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# \q
```

I can have access to postgres but I have that `perl` warning.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson I did it but I still get the same

Comment: Yeah, I typed too fast. ;) The problem is that `UTF-8` value for `LC_CTYPE`. No such locale name exists on Ubuntu. Do you possibly access the server remotely from a Mac machine?

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson yes exactly

Answer (score 0):

A workaround which may work is to edit the `~/.profile` file and add the line:

```
unset LC_CTYPE
```

That would prevent the invalid `UTF-8` locale name from being present in the environment of the user session.

Comment: Where is the location of ` ~/.profile`

Comment: @emax: `/home/[username]/.profile`

Comment: the problem is that it does not recognize my keyboard anymore and I can not type properly.

Comment: @emax: That's another and probably unrelated problem. Maybe you want to ask a new question.